# Edit an excel file on the server side in a client server architecture

Tags: java, excel, file, path, apache-poi

I have an excel book which is shared across all the business users. As part of the process, the excel needs to be updated at the server side. All users have mapped to a network drive which contains the excel book. Earlier we used to update the excel on the client side using activeX controls. Now the problem is that the path for the excel book is not accessible on the server machine and hence it's throwing file not found exception. Is there any way to handle this apart from mapping the network drive on the server machine as well?

Following is the code:
public static String updateExcelFile(String fileLocation, String dataVal,String txnId) throws IOException{

```
String status="";
//fileLocation = "Z:\\check.xlsx";
//FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\JXL\\Checklist OnBoarding1.1.xlsx"));

//fileLocation.rep
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (file);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

Row r = null;
Cell c = null;


String data[] = dataVal.split(",");


int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

int rowNum = rowCount;

Iterator<Row> rowInterator =sheet.iterator();
while(rowInterator.hasNext()){
    r=rowInterator.next();

    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = r.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()){

        c=cellIterator.next();
        //System.out.println();
        switch(c.getCellType()) {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.print(c.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
            if(c.getNumericCellValue()==Integer.parseInt(txnId)){
                int modRow = r.getRowNum();
                System.out.println("ModRow"+modRow);
                rowNum=modRow;
            }
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.print(c.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
            if(c.getStringCellValue().equals(txnId)){
                int modRow = r.getRowNum();
                System.out.println("ModRow"+modRow);
                rowNum=modRow;
            }
            break;
    }



    }
}


if(rowNum==rowCount){
    r=sheet.createRow(rowNum+1);
    r=sheet.getRow(rowNum+1);
}else{
    r=sheet.getRow(rowNum);
}



for(int cellNum =0; cellNum<data.length;cellNum++){

    c=r.createCell(cellNum);
    c.setCellValue(data[cellNum]);
}

file.close();


//FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\JXL\\Checklist OnBoarding1.1.xlsx"));
FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
wb.write(outFile);
outFile.close();
status="success";
```

return status;
}

Comment: when shall the server side process update the excel file?

Comment: @user2587106 on a button click from the page, there is an ajax call. At that time excel should be updated.

Comment: well, then send the excel file to the server when the user clicks the button.

Comment: OK, so u mean send the excel as JSON to the server. After that??

Comment: it's a little more involved, I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: Actually it's an automation project, and user wants automation to go exactly in the same way as they do it manually. They have an excel which they update as part of their process and the size is huge. Also they would not like to download it every time as on the same excel some macros are running.

Comment: I think I am left with no other option than mapping the network drive to server box as well. What's your opinion on this? Will I need office installed on the server box as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to map the network drive to the server box.

Comment: Also, I think you should not use Apache POI but some M$ means of automation such as as C#. That would let your automation use the same mechanisms as the excel users do.

Comment: thanks buddy for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

send the excel file to the server when the user clicks the button:

use ajax to upload the file to a servlet, 
have the servlet process the file and then respond to the client with a link to the updated file (which sits in a temp folder on the server), which the ajax can then present to the user.

The user can now download the excel and put it onto the network drive, where he and other users can edit it directly.

I guess this approach would require the user to at least accept the save operation.

Also this approach does not protect you from concurrent updates on the Excel: several users can have the server edit a copy of the Excel, and several other users could directly edit the excel on the network drive.

And having the server edit the Excel might be a problem if the Excel in question is large.

Well, I think I answered the question :-).

Comment: can u help me with password protected excels. I am getting some java cryptography extension error.

Comment: that's a different question